# Using a .load() Method to Detect and Deliver Multiple wrap() Functions Within?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function, load

I have developed a script that's intentional purpose is to grab (load) the first entry of content from the listed url source locations.

At those specific locations, whatever the first entry turns up to be, I would like the iframe (if detected within that entry) to have the corresponding wrap function applied to it, (as shown below).

Here's an example of the script:

```
$("#embed-content-div1").load("https://theurl.com/urltosource1/ #entry:first");
$("#embed-content-div2").load("https://theurl.com/urltosource2/ #entry:first", function(data) {
  $(function() {
    $("iframe.content1").wrap("<div class='content1-wrap'></div>");
  });
  $(function() {
    $("iframe.content2").wrap("<div class='content2-wrap'></div>");
  });
  $(function() {
    $("iframe.content3").wrap("<div class='content3-wrap'></div>");
  });
});
```

However, this particular script doesn't seem to be working consistently, and has malfunctioned on certain occasions in Chrome and Safari. It only seems to work best when the entire page is refreshed.

Is there a better way to achieve this, ensuring it would deliver a better, cross-browser performance overall?

Comment: Why put `$(function() { }` ? You do not need it.

Comment: What does *"malfunctioned"* even mean? That is a virtually meaningless technical problem statement

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I guess I picked the wrong wording for the question. What I meant to say is that the script performs invariably, and it is especially inconsistent in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I was just curious to know if there was any other way I could implement this with JQuery, alternatively to the way I have presented.

Comment: But what does inconsistent mean? You need to be a lot more specific. My guess is you are getting wrapped iframes in one but not the other and need to look inside each to wrap the iframes

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, it is something like that. Unfortunately, I can't provide a live example at the moment, so the best I could do was present the script as is, and see what could be advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out a solution which both repaired and improved the performance of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#embed-content-div2").load("https://theurl.com/urltosource2/ #entry:first", function(data) {
    $(function() {
      $("iframe.content1").wrap("<div class='content1-wrap'></div>");
    });
    $(function() {
      $("iframe.content2").wrap("<div class='content2-wrap'></div>");
    });
    $(function() {
      $("iframe.content3").wrap("<div class='content3-wrap'></div>");
    });
  });
});
$("#embed-content-div1").load("https://theurl.com/urltosource1/ #entry:first");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading the same content into each element you should probably look inside each element for the iframes to wrap. `load()` is asynchronous so the timing can be off when you only use one of the callbacks

Rather than duplicate the code for each you can do it in a simple wrapper function

```
function loadContent( selector, url){
  var $cont = $(selector);
  $cont.load(url, function(){
   $.each([1,2,3], function(_, num){
     $cont.find('iframe.content' + num).wrap('<div class="content'+ num +'-wrap"></div>')
   });   
  });
}

loadContent('#embed-content-div1','https://theurl.com/urltosource1/ #entry:first')
loadContent('#embed-content-div2','https://theurl.com/urltosource2/ #entry:first')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am going to try this out, and see how it performs.

Comment: Quick question though, what if the iframes did not have uniform names like `iframe.content1` and `iframe.content2`? In my project I have iframes, but they do not have uniform, numbered names. They appear more like `iframe.x_mediaplayer` and `iframe.y_audioplayer`.

Comment: Can you not use a generic class on iframes and/or wrappers?

Comment: The iframes are generated and embedded from other sites' APIs, so I cannot apply the generic classes like you presented in your answer. Would you like me to edit the code snippet from my original question, so that you would have a reference?

Comment: Can you not wrap them though with generic wrapper class? If not you need to provide all details

Comment: Actually, I can do that. Just not with the iframes.

Comment: You are back to being vague. I don't know how to interpet those 2 comments together

Comment: I meant, yes I can apply generic classes to the wrapper classes, but no I cannot apply them to the iframes.

Comment: Can't you just look for all iframes then? Change selector to `$cont.find('iframe').wrap(...`

Comment: I actually worked out a solution, but I appreciate the input you provided. I will definitely keep it in mind for future use!